# Using Latex in Javadoc comments

Tags: javadoc, gradle-plugin

I've inherited a bunch of code and they have LaTax in the Javadoc comments.
However, the locally developed gradle plugin that renders the LaTex to HTML has disappeared.
I'm looking for some other gradle plugin that can do that. I've googled quite a bit without success so I'm asking Stack Overflow!